# How to display php source code inside a post using visual editor?

Tags: php, visual-editor, code, html-editor

**NOTE**
I don't want the php code to be executed, only displayed.

I want to display this php code `<?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>` inside a post. I cannot make it work.

If I go to text type of editor and type `<pre class="lang:php nums:false"> <?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?> </pre>` there and save. I can see what I want to.

But when I switch to visual editor the php text is not there. There is box for it but the text is not there. If I save the post now html comments are added to the source code and it looks like `<pre class="lang:php nums:false"> <!--?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?--></pre>`. So when I then refresh the post page I got `!--` characters there, something that shouldn't be there.

Any idea how to display php code with syntax highlight?

Comment: Stay in the HTML editor and don't switch back and forth.

Comment: How do you then set up that is a code and div the pre tag a class?

Answer (score 2):

That may be a bit problematic. I use the plugin [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/syntaxhighlighter/), but as the plugin description says (my emphasis):

> TIP: **Don't use the Visual editor if you don't want your code mangled**. TinyMCE will "clean up" your HTML.

Another option is to embed Gists (or similar) using a Shortcode to pass the URL and let PHP render the `script` tag (as suggested by Marco Berrocal).

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/user/GistID.js"></script>
```

And the Shortcode path could also be used with [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields). Paste the script in the CF and pass its name to the Shortcode for rendering. The plugin Advanced Custom Fields comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would do a custom [Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), clean the PHP and display it on the way out.

Comment: It sounds bit too complicated to me.

Comment: Then perhaps you could look into a plug in? Sorry.

Comment: Marco, try to provide more details in an Answer, otherwise it's better to just make comment. @Radek, a shortcode is quite simple, ***much more simple*** than insert PHP in the visual editor. Research "conditional shortcode script" here in the archives

Comment: @brasofilo I would comment but don't have privileges for this yet (need 50 rep).

Comment: @brasofilo: not sure if I understood if shortcode could be a solution but what I don't want the php code to be executed, only displayed.

Comment: @brasofilo sorry chap, I didn't really know I had to craft a sophisticated answer if I couldn't comment. I wouldn't had I known.

Comment: There you go, welcome to commenting ;)